# using plantuml %load_json in DocToolchain

Tags: plantuml, doctoolchain

i try to use the possibility to schon an external json file in a class dirgram, embedded in an asciidoc fil using doctoolchain.

i'm able to reference the file with include:

```
----
include::../../plantuml/test.json[]
----
```

But that is not working:

```
!$remote_json = %load_json("../../plantuml/test.json")
```

However, if i use the absolute path, it works:

```
!$remote_json = %load_json("/home/user/git/project/src/test/resources/SAMPLE_CREATE_1.json")
```

There is a config param `plantuml.include.path`, but i've no idea where to set this in doctoolchain.

Any idea ?

Comment: Introduction of an internal function %loadJSON to load JSON data: https://github.com/plantuml/plantuml/pull/755

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't aware of the `%loadJSON` functionality, but if an absolute path works for you, then you should use the `projectRootDir` attribute in AsciiDoc.

When you use `src/docs` in docToolchain as base folder for your docs and this is located within `/home/user/projects/myprojects`, then `projectRootDir` points to `/home/user/projects/myprojects`.
So, to include `src/docs/test.json`, you can use `include::{projectRootDir}/src/docs/test.json[]`.

I hope this helps.